# Multiple SSH failing to run more than one command

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

When a use multiple SSH like below i am only able to run one command, if try to run more than one command its fails.

This thing is failing:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $PEM -t -t $APP_CLUSTER_USER@$APP_CLUSTER_IP "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $PEM -t -t $INSTANCE_USER@$INSTANCE_IP "rm -rf /home/$INSTANCE_USER/$INSTANCE_DEPLOY_DIR ;mkdir $INSTANCE_DEPLOY_DIR"" || exit 1
```

But breaking the same command into two runs properly.

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $PEM -t -t $APP_CLUSTER_USER@$APP_CLUSTER_IP "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $PEM -t -t $INSTANCE_USER@$INSTANCE_IP "rm -rf /home/$INSTANCE_USER/$INSTANCE_DEPLOY_DIR"" || exit 1

ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $PEM -t -t $APP_CLUSTER_USER@$APP_CLUSTER_IP "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $PEM -t -t $INSTANCE_USER@$INSTANCE_IP "mkdir $INSTANCE_DEPLOY_DIR"" || exit 1
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to nest a command using `""` inside another set of `""`. That doesn't work unless you backslash the inner pair. The way you have it, there are 2 quoted strings:

```
"ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $PEM -t -t $INSTANCE_USER@$INSTANCE_IP "
```

and

```
""
```

and an unquoted series of tokens in the middle:

```
rm -rf /home/$INSTANCE_USER/$INSTANCE_DEPLOY_DIR ;mkdir $INSTANCE_DEPLOY_DIR
```

so the semicolon is being interpreted by your original local shell, making the mkdir command entirely separate from the ssh.

The simplified version works by sheer luck. (The deciding factor is that you don't have a semicolon in the unquoted portion, but also you were lucky that ssh doesn't care whether the command you give it is in a single argument or not.)

Change the inner portion to

```
\"rm -rf /home/$INSTANCE_USER/$INSTANCE_DEPLOY_DIR ;mkdir $INSTANCE_DEPLOY_DIR\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kevin, this works.

I have found one more solution to this.

In the nested SSH we should use **single quote** instead of **double quote**.